# Как отследить измененияе надписи в контейнере div с помощью Mutation Observer и когда надпись изменится выполнить мою функцию?

Tags: javascript

На странице появляется `<div class="message">Подождите</div>` затем через 5 секунд меняется текст на `<div class="message">Забрать</div>` Как отследить появление `<div class="message">Подождите</div>` и как отследить изменение текста на `<div class="message">Забрать</div>`, после чего выполнить мою функцию  `myfunction()` ?

```js
const node = document.querySelector('article')
const callback = mt => {
  mt.forEach(o => {
    if (o.type != 'childList') return
    const od = o.target.classList.contains('message') 
      ? o.target 
      : o.target.querySelector('.message')
    if (!od) return
    const t = od.textContent
    // вот тут и выполняй свои действия в myfunction()
   document.querySelector('.message').style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important"); 
   console.log(`Выполнить действие для текста "${t}"`)
  })
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
const config = {
  childList: true, // наблюдать за непосредственными детьми
  subtree: true, // и более глубокими потомками
}
observer.observe(node, config);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.disable = true
  const html = `<dialog id='win'><p>Выполняются некие действия...</p><div class="message">Подождите</div></dialog>`
  node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
  win.show()
  //win.showModal()
  setTimeout(_ => {
    win.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Забрать'
  }, 2000)
})
```

```html
<article>
  <button>Показать окно</button>
</article>
```

Comment: На всякий случай уточню в каком месте кода происходит изменение надписи? Может и не нужно так отлавливать.

Comment: @Daniil Loban На странице элемента нет, когда нажимаешь на кнопку появляется окно на котором есть этот элемент `<div class="message">Подождите</div>` Проходит 5 секунд и в нём меняется текст `<div class="message">Забрать</div>` Незнаю этим уточнил я свой вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> На странице появляется Подождите затем через 5 секунд меняется текст на Забрать Как отследить появление Подождите и как отследить изменение текста на Забрать, после чего выполнить мою функцию myfunction() ?

Такое провернуть можно таким образом...

```js
const node = document.querySelector('article')
const callback = mt => {
  mt.forEach(o => {
    if (o.type != 'childList') return
    const od = o.target.classList.contains('message') 
      ? o.target 
      : o.target.querySelector('.message')
    if (!od) return
    const t = od.textContent
    if (t === 'Забрать') document.querySelector('.message').style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
  })
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
const config = {
  childList: true, // наблюдать за непосредственными детьми
  subtree: true, // и более глубокими потомками
}
observer.observe(node, config);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.disable = true
  const html = `<dialog id='win'><p>Выполняются некие действия...</p><div class="message">Подождите</div></dialog>`
  node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
  win.show()
  //win.showModal()
  setTimeout(_ => {
    win.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Забрать'
  }, 2000)
})
```

```html
<article>
  <button>Показать окно</button>
</article>
```

Comment: у меня код почему-то выполняет функцию сразу не дожидаясь смены текста.

Comment: @User, я неоднократно тебе уже писал - делай сам тестовые примеры. На них тебе более конкретно покажут пути решения. Пока же ты все ходишь по кругу и задаешь одни и те же вопросы...

Comment: ksa я попробовал вместо своей функции  окрасить  `document.querySelector('.message').style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");` Окраска уже происходит когда надпись Подождите появляется, а должно быть окрашено когда Забрать. Так что код  немного не тот который я хотел.

Comment: @User, "пробовать" у тебя пока плохо получается... Повторюсь - начинай делать тестовые примеры. Вставляй их в свои вопросы. На них тебе будут показывать варианты ответов. Как делать тестовые примеры я уже не однократно тебе показывал.

Comment: Куда этот тестовый пример вставлять? На что нажимать? Никак не соображу.

Comment: @User, давишь на "Править" у своего вопроса. А шаблон я тебе уже вставил...  Смотри на элементы управления этим шаблоном, там есть ссылка "редактировать пример кода" - попадешь в его редактирование. Вот там все и ваяй.

Comment: ksa Свершилось, я сделад тестовый пример. Ну он действительно не так работает как хотелось бы. Я про это с самого начала говорил.

Comment: @User, "я сделал" это громко сказано... :))) Ты просто вставил мой пример себе. И где же твоя `myfunction()`? Что ты в ней хотел делать?

Comment: @User, ты видно совсем не понимаешь что и как работает... Все что тебе нужно - это анализировать что находится в переменной `t` и делать соответствующие выводы. :( См.мой пример.

Comment: конечно не понимаю. Я чайник. Пытаюсь понять... Если-бы понимал, то не спрашивал)